# Change ImageView size programmatically

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout with 3 ImageViews. The first one is a square image, the second is just used for spacing, and the third one is another square image.

Here is the xml code for that layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/radioSV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/radioLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sssImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/radio_sss_400_r"
        android:layout_width="10sp"
        android:layout_height="10sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">
    </ImageView>

    <!-- spacing -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/spacing1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/sssImageView">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gaImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/radio_ga_400_r"
        android:layout_width="10sp"
        android:layout_height="10sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_below="@id/spacing1">
    </ImageView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now, I want my app to be useful for various screen densities, so therefore, in the java file, I ask for the density and use a switch-case statement afterwards. In this statement, the size (width, height) of the 2 ImageViews (`sssImageView` and `gaImageView`) have to be changed.

For instance, if the density of the screen is high, I want the width and height of the ImageViews to be 200sp. I've just put 10sp in the xml as a 'standard' value.

This is the part of the use-case statement for high screen density:

```
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(val_high, val_high);
    sssImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    sssImageView.setMaxHeight(val_high);
    sssImageView.setMaxWidth(val_high);

    gaImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    gaImageView.setMaxHeight(val_high);
    gaImageView.setMaxWidth(val_high);
    break;
```

Also, `val_high` is 200sp:

```
int val_high = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 200, this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Now, the part with the ImageView `sssImageView` works perfectly. It correctly enlarges the image from 10sp to 200sp (don't worry - the image is not 10sp originally!).
The **problem** is the fact that the other ImageView, `gaImageView`, puts itself on top of `sssImageView` and destroys the layout. If I comment out the 3 lines with `gaImageView`, it is on its correct place in the layout, but is still small (10sp) of course.

I have also tried the opposite: commenting out the 3 lines with `sssImageView` and only manipulating `gaImageView`. Now the top ImageView (`sssImageView`) is on its correct place and small as expected. However, the bottom ImageView, `gaImageView`, positions itself on top of `sssImageView`, and not below as written in the xml layout file.

What is wrong here?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious why not just use different drawables/layouts for different densities?

Comment: @Idistic I do. But if I don't change the size of the images too, the layout some places in my app is destroyed. This is one of those places. Actually, I have 3 different sizes for the images for these 2 ImageViews, but somehow they are not changed when testing on other densities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem.

Here is the code for the DENSITY_HIGH case statement:

```
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:               
    display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();               

    // 0.36 is a scaling factor
    int val_high = (int) (height*0.36);

    sssImageView.setId(1);
    gaImageView.setId(2);
    spacing.setId(3);

    layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(val_high, val_high);
    layoutParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(val_high, val_high);
    layoutParams3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));

    sssImageView.setMaxHeight(val_high);
    sssImageView.setMaxWidth(val_high);
    relativeLayout.updateViewLayout(sssImageView, layoutParams);            

    layoutParams3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, sssImageView.getId());
    relativeLayout.updateViewLayout(spacing, layoutParams3);

    layoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, spacing.getId());
    gaImageView.setMaxHeight(val_high);
    gaImageView.setMaxWidth(val_high);
    relativeLayout.updateViewLayout(gaImageView, layoutParams2);                
    break;
```

So generally, it looks like I had to "re-create" the xml file programmatically.