# android - RecyclerView item programmatically issues

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout, anko

I'm trying to create `RecyclerView` item programmatically using Anko library and I want to do all the stuff in one `RelativeLayout` for the best perfomance.

The title of my item should be `match_parent`, but it shouldn't cover flag marker (`hasImportantMessages`) or number on the right (`issues counter`), so I'm using this code to adjust `RelativeLayout` rules:

```
with(tvTitle.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) {
        removeRule(START_OF)
        removeRule(ALIGN_PARENT_END)

        when {
            hasImportantMessages -> addRule(START_OF, R.id.iv_important_messages)
            issueCounter > 0 -> addRule(START_OF, R.id.tv_issues_counter)
            else -> addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_END)
        }
    }
```

When RecyclerView creates first visible ViewHolders everything is fine, but when I scroll down a little and RecyclerView starts to reuse it's holders, I got some issues with it, check these screenshots.

[image: Good]

[image: Bad]

As you can see, RelativeLayout rules don't work properly. Title textView overlaps flag marker or issues counter textView. Maybe I should `invalidate()` somehow, but I already tried - doesn't work.

Comment: any specific reason for not doing it in xml?

Comment: Optimization. LayoutInflater uses lot of resourses and it takes some time to inflate xml.

Comment: and how many times it is called? maybe 6 max 8 times, does it really pay off? i dont think so...

Comment: Well, I can notice my RV lags a little bit with the first scrolling because it creates few ViewHolders to fill the pool. Also onCreateViewHolder called at least 3-4 times if I use smoothScrollToPosition(0) from the end of my list, I don't know why tho.

Comment: so how many times `onCreateViewHolder` is called in total? btw you can create a small pool of views using `LayoutInflater` so you dont have to use `inflate` method inside `onCreateViewHolder` method

Comment: 6-10 times after I attach my adaper and then 3-4 times everytime I use smoothScrollToPosition(0).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `updateViewLayout` after updating rules?

Here is example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6801082/6055194

Comment: The radical solutions are
1) To use multiple layouts https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/6055194
2) Replace RelativeLayout by ConstraintLayout